In go-redis, is it necessary to pass in any `keys` to the `Unwatch()` function?
In tx.go (part of the go-redis library), the Unwatch() function accepts an array of keys as a parameter.
However, I'm wondering if it is necessary to pass in any keys to Unwatch(). The Redis documentation seems to imply that UNWATCH does not need any additional arguments (see https://redis.io/docs/latest/commands/unwatch/).
Also, the Redis transactions docs say:

It is also possible to use the UNWATCH command (without arguments) in order to flush all the watched keys

So if I were to simply call Unwatch(ctx) in Go, would this flush all the keys?
When testing locally, calling Unwatch(ctx) without any keys seems to run fine and without errors, however there isn't an easy way to verify the keys were actually flushed.

It is not necessary to pass key arguments to the UNWATCH command for the reason stated in the question. The call Unwatch(ctx) executes the UNWATCH command with no keys.  The Unwatch method's keys argument is a variadic string, not an array.

@CeriseLimón thanks for the response. I’m curious then why would the command in go-redis accept any keys as arguments? The documentation doesn’t mention flushing specific keys.

Ask the go-redis developers why the Unwatch method has a keys argument.
